# How to put an API return string into an array

Tags: php

I have a string that i get from an API and i wish i could put it in a array so i could check the values that came from the return.

String return example:

```
{
  "code":"000",
  "message":"XXX",
  "date":"2018-05-17",
  "hour":"09:16:09",
  "revision":"",
  "server":"XX",
  "content":{
     "nome":{"info":"SIM","conteudo":[{"field1":"XXXX","field2":"XX"}]}
  }
}
```

What I need:

```
echo $string['code'];
```

Javascript has no problem with JSON encode command. But how can I do it with PHP?

Comment: `json_decode($string, true)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your JSON data seems to be invalid (***Some brackets missing***). It needs to be like this:-

```
{
    "code": "000",
    "message": "XXX",
    "date": "2018-05-17",
    "hour": "09:16:09",
    "revision": "",
    "server": "XX",
    "content": {
        "nome": {
            "info": "SIM",
            "conteudo": [{
                "field1": "XXXX",
                "field2": "XX"
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

***Now You need*** to decode this JSON data and then get data based on the index

```
$array = json_decode($json,true);

echo $array['code'];
```

Output:-https://eval.in/1005949

Comment: Thank you. It worked.
The brackets are missing because the return was too long so i cut it to fit better here.

Comment: @LuanWincardt  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 0):

You can decode the JSON string to Array in PHP.

```
$str = '{"code":"000","message":"XXX","date":"2018-05-17","hour":"09:16:09","revision":"","server":"XX","content":{"nome":{"info":"SIM","conteudo":[{"field1":"XXXX","field2":"XX"}]}';
$decodedValue = json_decode($str, true);

var_dump($decodedValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example string is not valid json, you are missing some closing brackets.

This should be the correct way:

```
'{"code":"000","message":"XXX","date":"2018-05-17","hour":"09:16:09","revision":"","server":"XX","content":{"nome":{"info":"SIM","conteudo":[{"field1":"XXXX","field2":"XX"}]}}}'
```

As for your question. in PHP you can easily use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Example:

```
<?php
$json = '{"code":"000","message":"XXX","date":"2018-05-17","hour":"09:16:09","revision":"","server":"XX","content":{"nome":{"info":"SIM","conteudo":[{"field1":"XXXX","field2":"XX"}]}}}';

$decoded_json = json_decode($json, true);
echo $decoded_json['code'];
```

You can see it working [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6ca6f01b637b512d103e676c550b551fee459d81)